# For lines matching in the first column, create a "X see also Y" list using second column

Tags: awk, regular-expression

For wikidata I want to create QuickStatments to assign  P1889 values for forts with identical names. This can be simplified to.

For a file with:

```
Fort George,Q12
Fort George,Q56
Fort George,Q678
Fort Anne,Q3
```

I want an exact match on the first column, and then output all the matching pairs in the form X see also Y.

```
Q12 see also Q56
Q12 see also Q678
Q56 see also Q12
Q56 see also Q678
Q678 see also Q12
Q678 see also Q56
```

The file is sorted by the first column. This feels like an awk problem, but I bounced off writing one

Comment: Rather than fixing your original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943273/for-lines-matching-in-the-first-column-create-a-x-see-also-y-list-using-secon, you came here and asked it again. Cross site posting

Comment: Just FYI, the reason you're getting many downvotes (both here and in stackoverflow) is that people expect to see that you've already tried something yourself. If you haven't demonstrated in your question any attempt of your to attack the problem (or even some basic idea you have), it comes off as rude and lazy and creates the impression that you think those sites provide coding services by demand. The goal of those sites is to help people learn and develop, and not to solve problems for them or do the work they're not willing to do.

Comment: Next time, please try to show some personal attempt, in any language, and tell us where you're stuck. It will show that you're trying to solve your own problems and that your goal is to learn and develop your skills. You'll receive a warm welcome and won't get hostile responds as you have.

Comment: Recent comments on Trustpilot suggests your approach isn't working. https://www.trustpilot.com/review/stackoverflow.com?sort=recency. I'm just pleased 3 people have offered to help me.

Comment: @vicarage I saw your query on SO and would have closed this question (as a cross-posting)  if it wasn't for the fact that it was closed on SO at that point already.  In general, if a question is not well formulated on one site, the same thing won't be well formulated on any of the other sites either.  Here too, we would rather see that you have attempted to solve your issue yourself before giving you an answer. That way, it would be possible for us to actually help you with the approach that you yourself attempted.

Comment: Who cares what bitter people on some random web site whinge about?   The point is, Q&A sites like this have no use for poorly written questions.  If you want good answers, your best bet is to ask good questions - and that includes being very clear in what you're asking and describing (or showing the code for) what you've already tried and what happened when you tried it. If you don't do that, most people will ignore your question, some will ask you to provide the missing details, and some might take pity and try to answer even though the answer might mis-interpret your poor question.

Comment: In short, it's in your best interest to ask good questions.  See the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), which has a link under the `?`-in-a-circle drop-down menu at the top of every page.

Comment: What a few people on "trustpilot" who didn't understand how to use the site say is totally irrelevant. I only answered this question because someone had already posted an answer in awk so I wanted to provide an alternative for the sake of others reading this in future, otherwise I'd just have downvoted, close voted and moved on.

Comment: Also, if any of the answers here satisfied your question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark ("V") beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. That's how you thank someone who made the effort and came up with the answer that helped you. It will also mark your question as "answered".

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to first collapse the 2nd field based on the 1st field (sorting not really needed), and then loop through the collapsed 2nd field to print the combinations of strings:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N nest --ivar : -f 2 then put -q 'a = splita($2, ":"); for (i in a) { for (j in a) { i != j { print i . " see also " . j } } }' file
Q12 see also Q56
Q12 see also Q678
Q56 see also Q12
Q56 see also Q678
Q678 see also Q12
Q678 see also Q56
```

The intermediate result, after the `nest` operation, looks like this:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N nest --ivar : -f 2 file
Fort George,Q12:Q56:Q678
Fort Anne,Q3
```

The `put` expression pretty-printed:

```
a = splita($2, ":");

for (i in a) {
    for (j in a) {
        i != j { print i . " see also " . j }
    }
}
```

You can follow the same pattern in `awk`, but you must first assume that your input is *simple* CSV (i.e., does not contain embedded commas or newlines etc.), and it becomes a bit more verbose:

```bash
$ awk -F , '{ d[$1] = d[$1] == "" ? $2 : d[$1] ":" $2 } END { for (k in d) { split(d[k],a,":"); for (i in a) for (j in a) if (i != j) printf "%s see also %s\n", a[i], a[j] } }' file
Q56 see also Q678
Q56 see also Q12
Q678 see also Q56
Q678 see also Q12
Q12 see also Q56
Q12 see also Q678
```

The `awk` code pretty-printed:

```c
{
    d[$1] = d[$1] == "" ? $2 : d[$1] ":" $2
}

END {
    for (k in d) {
        split(d[k], a, ":")

        for (i in a) for (j in a)
            if (i != j) printf "%s see also %s\n", a[i], a[j]
    }
}
```

Note that using `in` to access the indexes of an associative array in `awk` does not guarantee any specific ordering.  To fix the ordering, use an arithmetic loop instead.  I'm not showing this here as it's even more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk that supports `delete array` (which most do) and only storing the $2 values for one $1 at a time in memory:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=" see also " }
    $1 != prev {
        delete a
        prev = $1
    }
    {
        for ( i in a ) {
            print $2, i ORS i, $2
        }
        a[$2]
    }
' file
Q56 see also Q12
Q12 see also Q56
Q678 see also Q56
Q56 see also Q678
Q678 see also Q12
Q12 see also Q678
```

If your awk doesn't support `delete a` then **get a new awk** but you can also use `split("",a)` instead in any awk.

Pipe the output to `sort` if you want a different order of output lines.

Comment: I was not aware that `delete array` was not a standard way of deleting all entries in an array. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're welcome. Though not part of POSIX yet, `delete array` is so omnipresent these days that I sometimes forget to put that caveat in my answers that use it and I'm not sure I've ever seen anyone complain that their awk version doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

The following perl script uses a Hash-of-Arrays ("HoA") data structure (see [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) and [perldoc perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol) and related documentaion).

In short, a "HoA" is an associative array (AKA "Hash") where each element stores an indexed array containing zero-or-more data elements (an array can be empty - in this case, each array will have at least one element because it isn't created unless there's an element to add to it).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<<>>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /\s*,\s*/;
  push @{ $a{$F[0]} }, $F[1];
}

foreach my $k (sort keys %a) {
  my @values = @{ $a{$k} };
  foreach my $v1 (@values) {
    foreach my $v2 (@values) {
      print "$v1 see also $v2\n" unless $v1 eq $v2;
    }
  };
};
```

First it reads each line of input, stripping the newline at the end of each line and splitting the line into array `@F` on commas (ignoring any whitespace that may or may not be adjacent to the commas).  It then uses the first element of @F as a key to the a hash `%a` and pushes (i.e. appends) the second element of @F into the array stored in that element of %a.

When it has read all the input, it iterates over the keys of %a and then iterates twice, nested, over values in the arrays within those keys, printing lines only when the values differ.

I've sorted the keys of %a, but that's not necessary - it just guarantees consistency of output as perl hashes are inherently un-ordered (as they are in most languages).  Without sorting they'd come out in a seemingly random order on each run.

You could sort the @values array too, but (since the values are a mixture of letters and digits) it's probably not worth the bother unless you want to implement a natural sort algorithm (sometimes known as "version sort") or use [Sort::Naturally](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) or [Sort::Versions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Versions) or one of the other natural sort modules on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=natural+sort).  As is, the values will be output in the same order they were read.

Technically, the `@values` array in the output loop isn't needed.  I could have just used `@{ $a{$k} }` in both of the `$v1` and `$v2` loops, but IMO it's easier to read and understand this way.

Sample output from your sample input after saving the script as `see-also.pl` and making it executable with `chmod`:

```
$ ./see-also.pl input.txt 
Q12 see also Q56
Q12 see also Q678
Q56 see also Q12
Q56 see also Q678
Q678 see also Q12
Q678 see also Q56
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `datamash` to group the data and bash brace-expansion to get the combinations, e.g.:

```
<infile datamash -st, --output-delimiter=$'\t' -g1 collapse 2 |
cut -f2                                                       |
while read; do
  bash -c "printf '%s\n' {$REPLY}$'\t'{$REPLY}"
done                                                          |
awk '$1 != $2 { print $1 " see also " $2 }'
```